# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' after install it

Tags: python, selenium

I install **selenium** and webdriver  in my system so I got this issue much time 
my code :

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
sleep(5)
browser.close()
```

the issue

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\instagram\main.py", line 2, in 
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Comment: Did you install `selenium` on the correct python version and environment? Normally, `pip3 install selenium` for `py3` and `pip install selenium`, for `py2`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing selenium using

1. pip 3 if you're on a mac
2. pip if you're on windows

Or maybe you just need to upgrade pip or something

You could also try going to https://www.selenium.dev/ or https://pypi.org/project/selenium/

If this doesn't work can you give a few more details... I'll see if I can help!